# How to find a pointer to a function by string

Tags: c++, c, llvm, function-pointers, jit

I have a list of functions in a text file that I'd like to expose to LLVM for its execution engine at run time, I'm wondering if its possible to find pointers to the functions at runtime rather than hard code in all the GlobalMappings by hand as I'd probably like to add in more later. For example:

```
    // File: InternalFunctions.txt
    PushScreen
    PopScreen
    TopScreen

    // File: ExposeEngine.cpp
    // Somehow figure out the address of the function specified in a string
    void* addy = magicAddress("PushScreen");
    jit->addGlobalMapping(llvmfunction, addy);
```

If this is possible I love to know how to do it, as I am trying to write my game engine by jit-ing c++. I was able to create some results earlier, but I had to hard-code in the mappings. I noticed that Gtk uses something along the lines of what I'm asking. When you use glade and provide a signal handler, the program you build in c will automatically find the function in your executable referenced by the string provided in the glade file. If getting results requires me to look into this Gtk thing I'd be more than happy to, but I don't know what feature or part of the api deals with that - I've already tried to look it up. I'd love to hear suggestions or advice.

Comment: So, basically, you have some basic runtime, that you want to connect to some JITed code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Look at the man pages for `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`: these functions are standard on *nix systems and let you look up symbols (functions or variables) by name.  There is one significant issue, which is that C++ function names are usually "mangled" to encode type information.  A typical way around this is to define a set of wrapper functions in an `extern "C" {}` block: these will be non-member, C-style functions which can then call into your C++ code.  Their names will not be mangled, making them easy to look up using `dlsym()`.

This is a pretty standard way that some plugin architectures work.  Or at least used to work, before everyone started using interpreted languages!

Comment: For some other marginally popular systems, try `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: So, I found a way to get the C++ mangled names by the use of llvm ir output. I have a problem with it though because dlsym finds only 1 of my functions,returns a non null address but not any of the others. I wonder why this is.

Comment: Actually, I figured that out... it hit me just a few minutes ago. Dlsym wasn't finding the other functions because they are all inline. However it was finding one of the inline functions, so I wonder if dlsym can find a reference to a function? Or if the inline functions are created as a result of being called?

Comment: Inline functions are also emitted out-of-line in certain conditions, including if their address is ever taken.  They may be inlined at some call sites still.